# ElasticSearch: Indexing with multiple mapping types

Tags: post, indexing, get, mapping, elasticsearch

I am trying to fully comprehend indexing with multiple mapping types in ElasticSearch. In the docs it gives example code:

```
PUT my_index 
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": { 
      "_all":       { "enabled": false  }, 
      "properties": { 
        "title":    { "type": "string"  }, 
        "name":     { "type": "string"  }, 
        "age":      { "type": "integer" }  
      }
    },
    "blogpost": { 
      "properties": { 
        "title":    { "type": "string"  }, 
        "body":     { "type": "string"  }, 
        "user_id":  {
          "type":   "string", 
          "index":  "not_analyzed"
        },
        "created":  {
          "type":   "date", 
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this mapping how would I then create and search on an object?

For create would it be:

```
POST my_index/user/blogspot
```

or

```
POST my_index/user,blogspot
```

For searching would it be:

```
GET my_index/user/blogspot
```

or

```
GET my_index/user,blogspot
```

or something else?

An example of a POST and GET with multiple mapping would really help me out. Thank you so much!